# Not getting return value from ORACLE Function in c#

Tags: c#, oracle10g

**Below is my C# code to get value from oracle function :**

```
 public Int16 CheckGeneralSetting(string p_SysName, string p_UsrName)
        {
            try
            {
                conopen();
                Int16  retVal = 0;
                using (OracleCommand sc = new OracleCommand("udsp_Check_Gen_Setting", PubFun.ConOrcl))
                {
                    sc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    sc.Parameters.Add("p_SysName", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = p_SysName.Trim();
                    sc.Parameters.Add("p_UsrName", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = p_UsrName.Trim();
                    var mgrParam = sc.Parameters.Add("retval", OracleDbType.Int16,10, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
                    sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conclose();
                    retVal = Convert.ToInt16(mgrParam.Value);
                }
                return retVal;
            }
            catch { return 0; }
            finally {  }
        }
```

**Below is My Oracle Function:-**

```
create or replace FUNCTION udsp_Check_GEN_SETTING 
(
  p_SysName XXES_LOGRECORD.SYSNAME%TYPE ,p_UsrName XXES_LOGRECORD.USRNAME%TYPE  
) 
RETURN NUMBER IS 
  retval NUMBER(10);
  v_Cou_ number(10);
  v_Max_ number(10); 
  Begin  
  retval:=0;
  Select COUNT(*) INTO v_Cou_ from XXES_GEN_SETTING where Check_Type='Lic_Active' and IsActive='Y'; 
  if v_Cou_>0 Then 
      Select Check_Value INTO v_Max_ from XXES_GEN_SETTING where Check_Type='Lic_Active' and IsActive='Y';  
      Update XXES_LOGRECORD Set LogoffTime=SYSTIMESTAMP where abs(trunc(sysdate) - TRUNC(MODIFYLOGTIME)) >30; 
      Select count(*) INTO v_Cou_ from XXES_LOGRECORD where SysName=p_SysName and UsrName=p_UsrName and LogoffTime is null; 
      if v_Cou_=0 Then
            Select COUNT(*) INTO v_Cou_ from XXES_LOGRECORD where LogoffTime is null; 
            if v_Cou_<v_Max_ Then 
                Insert into XXES_LOGRECORD (SysName,UsrName,LogTime,ModifyLogTime) values (p_SysName,p_UsrName,SYSTIMESTAMP,SYSTIMESTAMP);  
                retVal:=1;
            Else 
                retVal:=0;
            End if;  
       Else 
            Update XXES_LOGRECORD Set ModifyLogTime=SYSTIMESTAMP where SysName=p_SysName and UsrName=p_UsrName and LogoffTime is null; 
            retVal:=1;
       End if; 
  Else
        Update XXES_LOGRECORD Set LogoffTime=SYSTIMESTAMP where abs(trunc(sysdate) - TRUNC(MODIFYLOGTIME)) >30; 
        Select count(*) INTO v_Cou_ from XXES_LOGRECORD where SysName=p_SysName and UsrName=p_UsrName and LogoffTime is null;  
        if v_Cou_=0 then
          Insert into XXES_LOGRECORD (SysName,UsrName,LogTime,ModifyLogTime) values (p_SysName,p_UsrName,SYSTIMESTAMP,SYSTIMESTAMP); 
        else 
          Update XXES_LOGRECORD Set ModifyLogTime=SYSTIMESTAMP where SysName=p_SysName and UsrName=p_UsrName and LogoffTime is null;
        end if; 
        retval:=1;
  End if;
  return retval;
End;
```

*

> Now my problem is ,I am not able to get return value from oracle function in my c# function. I am
>   getting my output in SQL developer from this Oracle function but not
>   from C# code. Value always comes 0 if i check mgrParam.value in c# but in sql developer its comes 1 which is correct. Error also coming while converting the output parameter (screenshot attached)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXili.png). Any help ?

*
**Below is my calling in SQL developer :**

```
set serveroutput on
begin
 dbms_output.put_line ('output' || ' ' || udsp_Check_GEN_SETTING ('prem','prem'));
   end;
```

Error screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should retrieve the value before closing the connection:

```
retVal = Convert.ToInt16(mgrParam.Value);
conclose();
```

Comment: Thanks dasblinkenlight. Problem solved after following Dom Cotton suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the input parameter to your variable, but when its being populated inside the Oracle logic you are not extracting it out of the parameter collection:

```
sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
var retVal = sc.Parameters["retval"].Value;
```

Also note that Oracle likes to have the return value as the first parameter regardless of what you name it inside C#:

```
using (OracleCommand sc = new OracleCommand("udsp_Check_Gen_Setting", PubFun.ConOrcl))
{
    sc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sc.Parameters.Add("retval", OracleDbType.Int16,10, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
    sc.Parameters.Add("p_SysName", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = p_SysName.Trim();
    sc.Parameters.Add("p_UsrName", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = p_UsrName.Trim();

    sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conclose();
    retVal = Convert.ToInt16(sc.Parameters["retval"].Value);
}
return retVal;
```

Comment: You're welcome, would appreciate an upvote and a mark for correct answer :)